# When is it appropriate to vote to close as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

An interesting discussion about duplicate closures happened in [this question's](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/335783/25936) comments section:

[image]

Personally, I'm in the "duplicate means *duplicate question*" camp. However, since it appears two veteran users are of a different opinion, I thought it would be best to put the question to the wider community.

What do you think? When is it appropriate to vote to close a question as a duplicate? Should the two questions be asking the same, or is it enough if the one's answers answer the other?

Comment: as sort of a prequel, consider [edit]ing this to add similar discussion that took place about half month ago: [six comments starting from this one](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/334671/is-coupling-a-good-thing-or-bad-thing-when-im-developing-standalone-modules-in#comment714423_334671): "Strictly speaking, answers don't make a post a duplicate target..." etc

Comment: @gnat: I think this site would really benefit if whenever you are tempted to vote for a dupe, take a deep breath, count to ten, and ask yourself for a moment "will it be clear for others that this question is a dupe". And when the answer is "unsure", please, don't vote for closing, just leave a "related, maybe a dupe" link. That would probably avoid a lot of destructive discussions here.

Comment: @DocBrown I almost bought your comment until I noticed that you have an answer in the question we discuss and might be simply afraid of getting it compete with brilliant [canonical](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/180588/31260) in case if duplicate is confirmed. Got to be tempting to squeeze a little bit of easy rep in your neck of woods instead of trying to beat or improve canonical post; Hans probably has a point when he wrote about ["voting force"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/839601) driving the changes that degrade original idea of a great Q&A site

Comment: @gnat: Really, *really* irrelevant.

Comment: @gnat: I can assure you, my comment was not motivated by that question in special. Will you "buy" my comment if I delete my answer from that question? Say "yes" and I will be happy to delete it.

Answer (score 6):

The guidance for duplicate questions is [very clear and specific](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/).  In a nutshell:

> **If you're going to close a user's question as a duplicate, it has to be a real duplicate.** For example, if a user asks, "What does the IP address 128.0.1.1/24 mean?" it's OK to close that as a duplicate of a more general question like "What do IP addresses of the form a.b.c.d/e mean?" But it's not OK to close it as a duplicate of a twenty-seven page guide to netmasks. That's the moral equivalent of saying ["RTFM."](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=RTFM)

Nor is it OK to close a question as a duplicate of a seemingly unrelated question that happens to provide an answer that fits the new question.  ***That's not a duplicate.***  It's just coincidence.  It's not helpful to point people at some random post and say "You're answer is over here somewhere."

Comment: If it's not useful to point people to where they can find the answer to their question, then why do we have duplicates in the first place?  Why do we even have *answers* in the first place if pointing someone to the answer to their question is something that "is not helpful".

Comment: Because "Why the f*ck did you point me to a question about Tahiti when I asked about Hawaii?  I know they're both surrounded by water, but damn."

Comment: "Because finding the area of an island is done the same way whether you're on Tahiti or Hawaii?"  If there's an underlying question in which one island is given where it being another doesn't change the answer, then the questions can be marked as duplicates, despite not being the same question.  Of course, if the question is asking something for which it being about Tahiti vs. Hawaii would change the answer, then of course they don't have the same answer, and they're not duplicates.

Comment: @Servy: The proper way to do that is to stand up a canonical question about islands in general, and close as a dupe of that, or modify the original question so that it has more general utility (if, in fact, the two OPs are actually asking about the same general principles).

Comment: @Servy: let me tell you I am backing up Robert here. Questions should be closed as dupes if the other *question* is either an immediate dupe, or a more general version of the same question. If answers just fit by coincidence, that is IMHO not enough for a closing reason.

Comment: @DocBrown Again, the tautological definition of, "it's a duplicate if it's a duplicate" is not a useful metric.  It provides no means for someone to figure out what to do in any situation.  Your fear of "coincidental answers" is unfounded; I challenge you to find even one example of entirely unrelated questions that have nothing to do with each other that just *coincidentally* happen to have the same quality answer (by SE's standards of quality for an answer).  You'll only ever find questions with the same answer when the questions are similar enough that you'd want them to be closed.

Comment: @Servy: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9743/does-this-meta-policy-overrule-our-meta/9748#9748

Comment: @Servy: *"You'll only ever find questions with the same answer when the questions are similar enough that you'd want them to be closed"* - that actually sounds to me you agree that questions should to be closed only if they are "similar enough" to be a clear dupe.

Comment: @DocBrown Yes, but I'm phrasing the actual guideline that I would explain to others in such a way that they have a clear and understandable metric to follow, rather than an entirely ambiguous statement of "similar enough" that is unclear and highly subjective.  By defining "similar enough" to be when a good answer to one answers the other you have provided a means for anyone to determine when questions are "similar enough" and when they're different enough that they should have their own answer and not be closed.

Comment: @Servy: if answers to one question are serving well to another question can be at least as similar subjective as if one question is asking the same as another one. Actually, I think *both* should match - the question should be the same, or a little bit more general, and the answers to the dupe should be good answers to the new question. And the primary "metrics"  I favour here is common sense.

Comment: @DocBrown And that can be good enough for a handful of very active users who've seen a lot of questions, are very familiar with the site, it's goals, and lots of examples of when closures have gone well and gone poorly.  When you tell new users to close questions based purely on "common sense" you don't always get a great result.  Likewise, when someone asks why their question was closed and you say, "it's just common sense", and if they ask what they need to do to get it opened and you say, "when my common sense says that it should be" that's not necessarily going to be good enough for them.

Comment: @Servy: that is why you need at least 3000 rep for voting to close.

Comment: @DocBrown And yet many, many people have earned 3000 rep without having a good idea of when they should close a question (in part because there are people like you telling them that there are no criteria at all by which they should judge whether or not a question should be closed, and that they should just do whatever they feel like doing).  It also means that you have no grounds for criticizing gnat for his decision to vote to close questions, when you state that the only criteria for when you should vote is whether or not you think the question should be closed.

Comment: @Servy: I did not say "no criteria", don't twist my words. Quite the opposite, I guess I expect stronger criteria than you for a legitimate close - the questions should match, the answers should fit, *and* I expect people should apply some common sense.

Comment: @DocBrown Again, you have not actually listed any criteria.  You're recursively defining your terms.  When you say questions should be closed when they're "a match" and you provide no definition of what a match is, then you *are* telling people to just do what they want.  You have provided no *useful* means for someone to determine when to close a question.  Given your "criteria", gnat's close vote is appropriate, because *his* common sense tells *him* that the questions are duplicates, and you're telling he he should only ever consider his common sense, and nothing else.

Comment: @Servy: this gets boring, you ignore what I am saying, twisting my words, ignore that I actually agree to you that also answers must be a good fit, and I don't like your tone. Sorry, I have better things to do.

Comment: @DocBrown How am I ignoring what you're saying?  You're ignoring what *I'm* saying.  All you've ever done is say that duplicates should be closed when they're duplicates, blatantly refused to provide any criteria for when questions actually *are* duplicates, and any time I've pointed out that you've not actually said anything meaningful you've resorted to attacking me while ignoring all of my arguments.  You haven't said anything that I could ignore.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is the same as the one that Servy presents in the comments captured above.

Question A is a duplicate of Question B if the answers to Question B answer Question A.

That said, there are some other considerations.

First, Question B may answer parts of, but not the entirety of, Question A. In that case, Question B should be linked to in the comments of Question A. This also causes it to show up in the sidebar of Question B. If necessary, answers can also link to one or more answers of Question A as supporting information.

Second, the answer to Question B cannot be hidden in one or more answers to Question A. The answer should be clearly obvious by reading the answers to Question B. If the answer is hidden away in a link to an external resource or a small aside, then Question B is not a duplicate at all.

Third, if both questions have answers, the quality of those answers should be used when considering duplication. Question A may be older, but if Question B attracted sufficiently high quality answers, then Question A should be marked as a duplicate of Question B.

See:

[The Wikipedia of Long Tail Programming Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/):

> If you're going to close a user's question as a duplicate, it has to be a real duplicate. For example, if a user asks, "What does the IP address 128.0.1.1/24 mean?" it's OK to close that as a duplicate of a more general question like "What do IP addresses of the form a.b.c.d/e mean?" But it's not OK to close it as a duplicate of a twenty-seven page guide to netmasks.

[Handling Duplicate Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/) discusses three kinds of duplicates. Two are easily closable as duplicates (the "cut-and-paste duplicate questions" and "accidental duplicates"). The third, the "borderline duplicate" covers the case that I describe above.

---

I would like to generally speak about voting to close as a duplicate, as well. One person's vote to close is a single opinion, one that just happens to leave an autogenerated comment that includes a link to the question they picked as a duplicate. That autogenerated comment does not need to be flagged as non-constructive, rude, or offensive. However, you can flag if  Also, you do not need to engage with people over a single close vote. I'd ask that no one votes blindly - if someone has suggested a question as a duplicate, read both questions and, if you feel they are duplicates, vote with them. If you don't feel that way, then don't vote to close as a duplicate. If the question has several close votes that you feel are inappropriate, then you should open a [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) here on Meta.

Comment: *[citation-needed]*

Comment: @RobertHarvey Done, with two links to the SO blog. Is that sufficient? Otherwise, I can keep going to find some Meta.SE posts.

Comment: Gnat's proposed duplicate (the one that started this conversation) doesn't fit any of those three kinds of duplicates, nor do any of those three kinds discuss closing a question as a duplicate because "you can find your answer over here."

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not speaking to the validity of that close-as-duplicate vote. This question is a generic discussion of what a duplicate is, not a question about that specific question and if it is a duplicate. If it doesn't fit the definition(s) above, then as other people review the question, they should see that and choose to not vote to close. Eventually, the close vote will expire.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Indeed.  The answer to the proposed duplicate question wouldn't actually be a good answer to the question he proposed it as a duplicate of.  That doesn't mean that two questions must be exactly the same for them to be duplicates.

Comment: @Servy: The answers are not relevant.  The question has to be a duplicate *first.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey *[citation-needed]*

Comment: I already provided one in my answer below.

Comment: A single vote to close is not a statement that it is a duplicate. It's a statement that one individual (out of 5) thinks that it is a duplicate.

Comment: The discussion's not really about gnat's bogus vote to close anymore.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You mean the quotation that describes how a question can be closed as a duplicate of a question that isn't actually asking the same thing as it?  Your citation provides a counter-example to your claim.

Comment: @Servy: I'm not really in the mood to rehash canonical posts here, and the constellation of problems that accompany them.  You know what I mean, and I know that you know what I mean.  Canonical posts are something that we can all agree on; they have no relevance to gnat's proposed close vote.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So given you *do* understand that questions that aren't actually asking exactly the same questions can potentially be duplicates, why continue to say otherwise?  I've only ever said that I felt that the one close vote in question wasn't appropriate; that has never been an issue.

Comment: @Servy: The sticking point is that you and gnat seem to think that you can  map a new question to some existing answer on some other question without considering what the original question is asking first.  *You can't.*  I never said that the questions have to be *exact* duplicates, I said that you have to map questions to questions, not question to answers.  Nor am I averse to considering the quality and relevance of the original answers, but the question to question mapping *has to succeed first.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey If the differences in the question aren't germane to the answer, why wouldn't you?  What do you gain from repeating the same answer again?

Comment: You see, you're still missing the point.  Vote to close as duplicate was *never designed to eliminate duplicate answers, only duplicate questions.*    A trivial, but hopefully useful example:  The two questions "What color should I paint my car" and "what color should I paint my mailbox" are not duplicates, even if the answer is "green," and even if the detail in both questions points to green being the correct answer in both cases.

Comment: @RobertHarvey A post explaining why it's a good idea to paint a mailbox green *wouldn't make a good answer for why you should paint your car green*.  The points wouldn't apply, making it a poor answer to the question.  The criteria you'd consider when determining the color of  your mailbox and your house are different, thus the answers to the two questions are different, even if the resulting color chosen is the same.  The differences in the question *are* germane to the answer, so the questions are *not* duplicates.

Comment: Of course, an exemplary answer to a question asking what color to paint your house if you have an odd numbered street address is going to be an exemplary answer to a question asking what color to paint  your house if you live on an even numbered street address.  The questions are different, but since *the differences in the question aren't relevant to the answer* they are duplicates.

Comment: @Servy: I'm sorry, but you're going to have a very hard time convincing me that "My boss asks me to stop writing small functions and do everything in the same loop" is ever going to be a duplicate of "Are there any OO principles that are practically applicable for Javascript," no matter what answers are posted there.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've said like 5 times now that I don't think that's a suitable duplicate.  Once again, *that is not a suitable duplicate target*.  The differences in the two questions are *absolutely* germane to the answers, and as a result, the answer to either question won't be an acceptable answer to the other.  I've never said that it would, so why keep bringing it up?

Comment: @Servy: Sorry, but I don't think I'm going to be able to untie that Gordian knot.  My position remains the same: if the two questions cannot in any reasonable way be considered duplicates, the answers are irrelevant; you can stop your analysis there.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What is so complicated about it that you don't understand?  It's *your* position that makes no sense at all.  "Questions are duplicates when they're duplicates, and they're not duplicates when they're not duplicates."  You've defined your term recursively.  You're basically defining questions as being duplicates whenever you say they are, which isn't a useful criteria for anyone but you to determine if a question is a duplicate.

Comment: @Servy: Let's try this again.  1.  Is the question a duplicate by any reasonable definition?  No?  STOP.  Yes?   2.  Does the dupe target satisfactorily answer the duplicate question?  No?  STOP.  Yes?  Its a duplicate.  Simple as that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Again, you're defining the term with itself.  If your answer to, "when are two questions duplicates" to say, "they're duplicates when they are duplicates" then you have provided no information of value.  You have merely stated a tautology.  The tautology is of course correct; it's correct by definition, but it's a useless statement to make.

Comment: @servy: Any assessment of duplication *must first evaluate the questions, without regard for the answers.*  Does that make better sense to you?  *This isn't a tautology; it's simply how this works.*  I think you're being pedantic about the wording I'm using; again, *you know what I mean, and I know that you know what I mean.*  If you're in any way involving the answers in your duplication checks without first checking the questions alone to see if they can reasonably be interpreted as duplicate, *you're doing it wrong.*

Comment: So if you're going to reject every definition presented to you other than the tautological one, how *do* you define duplicate questions?  I, and the SE guidelines, have defined questions as being duplicates when a quality answer to one is a quality answer to the other.  That's an entirely sensible definition to use, and you have yet to provide even a single instance (hypothetical or actual) in which that's not an effective metric to use, let alone your own alternative other than "do what you feel like", which isn't a useful guideline.

Comment: @Servy: The citation I pointed to already has a satisfactory definition for duplicate questions: *"if a user asks, "What does the IP address 128.0.1.1/24 mean?" it's OK to close that as a duplicate of a more general question like "What do IP addresses of the form a.b.c.d/e mean?" But it's not OK to close it as a duplicate of a twenty-seven page guide to netmasks."*  **Notice that it doesn't mention answers at all.**

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's one example.  It's not a definition.   Any acceptable answer to the latter question is going to be an acceptable answer to the former question.  Note you didn't need to actually see the answers to determine that.  If you can provide an acceptable criteria for determining if questions are duplicates that never even considers what their answers might be, great; let's hear it.  You also haven't provided any reason why it's important that one be prohibited from considering what the acceptable answers for a question are in determining if they're duplicates.  Why shouldn't you?

Comment: @Servy: I trust people like you not to abuse the "duplicate by virtue of the answer being duplicate" principle.  But not folks like gnat, who will beat everyone over the head with it over questions that clearly have only the most tenuous relationship with each other.  The principles of question duplication need to be simple and unambiguous enough to work for everyone, not just folks like you who can afford to be nuanced.  There's no such thing as perfect duplication mapping, and a few stray duplicates is not the end of the world; in fact, it's *by design.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey `The principles of question duplication need to be simple and unambiguous enough to work for everyone`  Agreed.  So what is your proposed alternative? I've provided the best example that I've ever seen, which also happens to be the standard policy.  If you can provide something that's clearer and/or simpler, I'd *love* to hear it.  So far you've only ever said questions are duplicates when they feel like duplicates, which isn't particularly simple and it's most *certainly* not unambiguous.

Comment: Frankly, this is starting to remind me of the "when is a not an answer answer not an answer" debate, and I've kinda lost interest.  I've given numerous examples, and you seem either unable or unwilling to take them in, so I think I'm done here.

Comment: So the existing definition isn't acceptable to you, and so it shouldn't be used anymore, but you have no interest in providing any alternative.  So...we should just tell people that there are no criteria for duplicates, and you should just do what you feel like?  If you think that'll slow gnat down I don't have good news for you.  While I have all the sympathy in the world for you not being able to solve the (very hard) problem of coming up with a better guideline, until someone does, I would think the existing guidelines should stick, no?  (Note, a few examples does not a guideline make.)

Comment: @Servy: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9743/does-this-meta-policy-overrule-our-meta/9748#9748

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'd say that everything that I've said here has been in line with that (note that quite a number of points you've raised would contradict that post).  Of course, that post is trying to be a bit *more* nuanced than me, something that you've said you're wary of.  Do you disagree with Shog's position?

Comment: @Servy: Nope.  But his position is pretty unambiguous: don't close questions as dupes just because the answers have the same animated gif in them. Pithy, but makes my point.  I guess I'm just very bad at explaining things.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The whole point of that example is that, in that case, the answers for the proposed duplicates aren't a quality answer for the question it is proposed as a duplicate of.  If you were just posting the answers of the duplicate to the question, rather than voting to close, they'd be *bad answers*, even though the questions are similar.  The litmus test has proven successful.

Comment: @Servy: But you can avoid the whole "gnat is a bot" effect by simply applying your litmus test to the question first.  Why are you so opposed to that?  There no harm in making sure the question is a reasonable duplicate first before looking at the answers, your cry fouls about tautologies notwithstanding.  You can apply the "answer is a dupe" metric sensibly, because you're a reasonable person.  gnat can't.  And at the end of the day, it's question dupes that we're casting close votes against, not answer dupes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm opposed to having the guideline of "only close questions when they're the same question" for precisely [this reason](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8312/?noredirect=1#comment26176_8315)  You end up with people reopening duplicate questions because there's some entirely irrelivant detail in one that makes them "not duplicate questions" even though the answer is the same.

Comment: @Servy: I've finally figured it out.  You need the answers to determine whether it's a dupe or not.  I don't.  There are clear guidelines for question duplication that don't require evaluating the answers; the material in my answer is all you really need to know to make that evaluation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Honestly I don't see why you have a problem explaining to gnat why his votes are wrong using guidelines I, and Shog, have described.  The answers on the duplicates he's often proposing *wouldn't make acceptable answers* to the questions he's voting to close.  If you were to copy-paste the answer over it *wouldn't* be a good answer.  I'm not sure if the problem is that he thinks they *would* be an acceptable answer, or if he just doesn't care, but either way, *that* is the real problem you'd need to figure out as a moderator to really deal with the situation.

Comment: @Servy: Trust me, I've tried.  My point, of course, is that his dupe calculus would be radically improved if he simply focused on *the questions,* and not the answers, as he seems incapable of integrating the two as you have.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It seems you really *don't* get it.  Using answers as a guidelines is the best way I've ever seen to explain it to someone without a lengthy conversation going over lots of nuance.  If I just tell someone, "close questions as a duplicate when you think they're close enough to being the same" I know they won't actually understand (correctly) what questions to close.  If I tell them, "if copy-pasting the answer to the question you're considering closing would make an acceptable answer, then you can vote to close as a duplicate" that they'll have a pretty good idea of what to do.

Comment: @Servy: That the *questions* must be dupes is not a fact in dispute.  We may disagree over the methods used to get there, but your method clearly does not work for gnat.  If there were a suitable answer on his proposed dupe, the two questions would *still not be duplicates.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey So you'd suggest completely changing the guidelines you use for everyone because one person seems to not understand the rule (or care, because if you've explained to him that he's doing something wrong and he hasn't adjusted his actions than he can't really say that he doesn't understand that he's doing something wrong).

Comment: @Servy: The guidelines I've described to you are the same ones that I've used for the last seven years to moderate Stack Overflow.  They are in no way contradictory to anything that Shog stated in his answer.  I'm not changing the guidelines; I am upholding them.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Perhaps this is the relevant point then; if you were to post the entire content of the duplicate's answers as an answer then it wouldn't make a quality answer, simply because there is so much off topic content; there's so much noise that, while the correct answer is contained in it, the *entirety* of the answer wouldn't be acceptable as a result.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Shog was pretty specific in stating in his post that it's a highly useful metric to judge whether questions are duplicates by determining if the answer(s) to one would make good answers to the other.  You saying that that's just not true is most certainly contradicting him.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that at all.  I'm saying that, if the titles of the two questions don't look even remotely similar, there's a very high degree of probability that they are not dupes, and you don't have to pursue the matter any further.  Gnat fails *because he starts with the answers first, and disregards the questions.*  See also http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8312/when-is-it-appropriate-to-vote-to-close-as-a-duplicate/8314?noredirect=1#comment26186_8312

Comment: Also, FWIW, as a moderator on Stack Overflow, a site that gets more than 800 flags per day, most of the mods do not have the luxury of this kind of deep analysis.  We're not required to moderate based on the *content* of questions and answers, so if it's not clearly apparent that a question is really a duplicate, we generally don't close.  This is also true of "when is a not an answer answer not an answer" flags.  My metric for those is simple: *"does this content belong here?"*

Comment: @RobertHarvey And yet, while uncommon, I've seen plenty of questions that seemed very different from the title alone, but upon actually looking at the posts, it becomes clear that there is the same underlying question, and an answer that answers that underlying question, so there's no need to duplicate it just because one question's title doesn't accurately describe what it's really asking. I also assume, based on what you've insinuated, that you've actually explained your feelings to gnat before, so it would seem that your approach to explaining duplicates doesn't actually solve that problem.

Comment: @Servy: He believes that "answers make questions duplicate."  Period.  I hope that's not what you believe.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's my understanding that close flags are largely left to the community, through the close vote queue.  I wouldn't consider it part of the responsibility of moderators to judge whether or not questions are duplicates, outside of a handful of edge cases where there is strong disagreement among the community as to what to do.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'd only amend it to say, "*high quality answers* make questions duplicates".  I've yet to ever see an example of two questions having the same *quality* answer that didn't have the same underlying question.  Of course, were I to formally define it myself, when not expecting inexperienced users to use the definition, I'd say that questions are duplicates if the differences in the questions would be irrelevant when providing a quality answer.

Comment: @Servy: Two things.  First, despite having a binding vote, I'm expected to use my votes just as the community would.  Second, questions don't get closed for all sorts of reasons, including "this has been answered over here before," a POV that I don't consider valid without evaluating the question also.  But there are other reasons.  Some questions just drop off the radar and never get closed.  Others are merely uninteresting, and don't get enough attention to close.  So there are plenty of flags that get raised that are non-contentious.

Comment: `I've yet to ever see an example of two questions having the same quality answer that didn't have the same underlying question.` -- Which means that evaluating *the questions* for duplication should still work.  In any case, while I see the effectiveness of your method, I don't see it as any easier to explain than mine.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sure.  The definition I provided later in that same comment is not at all dependant on the actual answers to the question. Using the *actual* answers a question has is simply easier than comparing the questions, and is less subjective, so it's a useful shorthand when trying to explain to someone new[-ish] how to properly judge duplicates.  It's hard to explain to someone how similar is "similar enough" to close, and what differences matter and what don't, when looking at questions in isolation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey `I don't see it as any easier to explain than mine.` To that I rely on observational evidence.  Gnat is the only person I've ever really seen with the problem we've shown here of someone consistently closing questions as duplicates of loosely/tangentially related questions that might have some relevant information in there somewhere, even though the answers wouldn't make good answers.  I've seen dozens of people reopening (or not closing) questions because there were trivial differences in them not actually relevant to any good answer.

Comment: A judicious edit of the question ought to solve that problem, if it genuinely addresses the same issue as the dupe.  Seriously, *they need to be the same question.*  Closing as dupe because "your answer is over there" just confuses everyone if the questions can't be reasonably interpreted to be the same.

Comment: @RobertHarvey To that I refer back to Shog's post.  *Overly* general questions can sometimes be worse than a more specific question that simply has a good general answer.  For example, when someone asks, "how do I print "hello world"?" I'm not compelled to edit that question to say, "how do I print an arbitrary string literal to the console".  It harms searchability.  And yet if someone tries to say, "but I'm trying to print 'goodbye world' not 'hello world', so that's not a duplicate" then I'm having none of that.  I don't feel compelled to edit the question before marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: You have an incomplete sentence in your final paragraph: "...rude, or offensive. However, you can flag if **[missing something here]** Also, you do not need to engage..."